# Lower bounds on roots of a polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let P be a degree 3 polynomial with complex coefficients such that the constant term is 2010. Then P has a root $\alpha$ with $|{\alpha}|>10$. Is this statement true or false?
I know that Rouche's theorem can help bound roots but that's only an upper bound on the modulus of roots. Also, the coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$ are unknown here so I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no restrictions on the coefficients then an easy counterexample is $2010x^3 + 2010$ which has 3 roots on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

If the leading coefficient is $1$, then from Viete's theorems you know that the product of the roots is (minus) the constant coefficient. Then at least one of the roots has to be equal or greater in absolute value than $\sqrt[3]{2010}>12$.

Comment: thanks! but in this case no such assumption is made

Comment: This should have been the context if the task had been direct and straightforward. As an "identify missing pieces" task, the other answer is of course correct.